# Cloning and Clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Im cloning an object on my page before I do anything with it:

```
var questionHTML = $('#questions:first').clone();
```

Then later I insert the clone into the page.
The problem is, no clicks work on the inserted clone, for example:

```
$(".addAnswerBtn").click(function() {});
```

The above addAnswerBtn in the cloned object no longer works (it works fine in the original), is there a way around this?

Comment: Why are you using `:first` with an ID selector?

Comment: You're cloning the ID too which must be unqiue.

Answer (score 0):

To clone an object with all of its events in tact, use `.clone(true)`.  Please see the jQuery API documentation on it: [enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in some comments, you are cloning an object with an ID.  Make sure you change the ID after cloning, or you could get some wacky results.

Comment: @j08691 Right.  I have seen other odd things like the original no longer works, but the clone does (how that happened, I don't know).  Weird things can happen when two items have the same ID.

Comment: Im actually cloning it's li so it's fine

Comment: .clone(true) does not work. And yes I have made sure im not cloning an element with an id

Comment: @user1013512 - according to the code in your question you are. Perhaps you should provide a better code example and a jsFiddle.